# How do I run C# 4.0 compiler with CSharpCodeProvider class?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, compiler-construction

I'm using this snippet

```
CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider =
   new  CSharpCodeProvider(
      new Dictionary<String, String> { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
```

for the 3.5 compiler for dynamic code compilation.

I'm assuming I should use `"v4.0"` to switch to the 4.0 compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed v4.0

Answer (score 4):

Besides specifying "v4.0", you will need to add the reference "Microsoft.CSharp.dll" in order to use the "dynamic" keyword.

```
var codeProvider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider(
new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } });
var parameters = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters 
{
    GenerateInMemory = true,
    GenerateExecutable = false,
    IncludeDebugInformation = true,
    TreatWarningsAsErrors = false
};
// Here add more referenced assemblies
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.CSharp.dll");
```

Don't forget to compile the solution using the Framework 4.0+.

I hope this helps.